# Caching with dynamic content

Tags: cache

My WP site is a little slow, but using WP Super Cache speeds it up. The problem is that many of the pages have dynamic content from the database that always needs to be uncached. 
Is there a compromise for doing both? E.g. caching parts that aren't dynamic like scripts, pictures, css? Or is there a way to leave shortcodes out of the cache, since all of my dynamic content is done via shortcodes in the theme functions.php?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I solved this. Found this very good tutorial/extension for W3TC http://www.xoogu.com/dynamic-shortcodes-extension-for-w3-total-cache 
I have tried this out and it works wonderfully and the difference is nice. Got a much better score on Pingdom speedtest.

Comment: dead link......

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: went out before, came back now.... answers that are based on external links are not true answers